# OpenERP 7 - Domain in Data File

Tags: odoo

i want to search an Existing Record in my Data File:

In the Database is an existing record (Model: ir.model):

> ID = ?
>
> MODEL = my.class

Now i want to search it in my Data File, because i have an Many2One relation:

```
<record model="ir.model" id="ir_model_id" domain="[('model', '=' , 'my.class']">

<record model="my.other.class" id="my_other_id">
  <field name="model" eval="ref('ir_model_id')"/>
</record>
```

or

```
<record model="my.other.class" id="my_other_id">
  <field name="model" res_model="" search="[('model', '=' , 'my.class']"/>
</record>
```

How can i search a existing Model ?